# In Vue.js, how can I get an event to fire in a select when the displayed element is chosen?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is an example fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/40fxcuqd/

Initially, it displays "Carl"

If I select Carol, Clara etc, then an event will fire and data will print to the console.

But if I click the dropdown and choose "Carl", no event will fire, and nothing will print to the console.

The event I'm using is @input:

```
<select v-model="selectedPerson" @input="myEvent()">
```

How can I get an event to fire every time something is selected, even if it's the same value?

Edit:

To clarify, when "Carl" is initially selected:

[image]

and then the dropdown is opened:

[image]

and then Carl is selected again, I would like an event to be triggered and a print to the console. My issue at the moment is no event is triggered, and nothing prints to the console.

Comment: I tried in Chrome and Firefox and it works fine for me. *Maybe you could change the event to `@change` to get the new selected data.*

Answer (score 1):

That is because the selected option by default is 1, then nothing change when you click on Carl, you must use @change event and if you want to get Carl value when you do click should use placeholder on select option.

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: `
        <div>
            <select v-model="selectedPerson" @change="myEvent()">
                <option :value="null" disabled hidden>Select option</option>
                <option v-for="person in people" :value="person.key" :selected="person.key == selectedPerson">{{person.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    `,
    data: {
        people: [
            {key: 1, name: "Carl"},
            {key: 2, name: "Carol"},
            {key: 3, name: "Clara"},
            {key: 4, name: "John"},
            {key: 5, name: "Jacob"},
            {key: 6, name: "Mark"},
            {key: 7, name: "Steve"}
        ],
        selectedPerson: null
    },
    methods: {
    myEvent: function() {
    console.log(this.selectedPerson);
    }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Really hacky but does the job, I've used `@click` and [`event.detail`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/detail) or [`event.which`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/which):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
        <div>
            <select v-model="selectedPerson" @input="myEvent($event)" @click="myEvent($event)">
                <option v-for="person in people" :value="person.key" :selected="person.key == selectedPerson">{{person.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    `,
  data: {
    people: [{
        key: 1,
        name: "Carl"
      },
      {
        key: 2,
        name: "Carol"
      },
      {
        key: 3,
        name: "Clara"
      },
      {
        key: 4,
        name: "John"
      },
      {
        key: 5,
        name: "Jacob"
      },
      {
        key: 6,
        name: "Mark"
      },
      {
        key: 7,
        name: "Steve"
      }
    ],
    selectedPerson: 1
  },
  methods: {
    myEvent: function(e) {
      if (e.detail == 0)//if (e.which == 0)
        console.log(e.type, this.selectedPerson);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 39px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

A less hacky way using data:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
        <div>
            <select v-model="selectedPerson" @input="myEvent($event)" @click="myEvent($event)">
                <option v-for="person in people" :value="person.key" :selected="person.key == selectedPerson">{{person.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    `,
  data: {
    people: [{
        key: 1,
        name: "Carl"
      },
      {
        key: 2,
        name: "Carol"
      },
      {
        key: 3,
        name: "Clara"
      },
      {
        key: 4,
        name: "John"
      },
      {
        key: 5,
        name: "Jacob"
      },
      {
        key: 6,
        name: "Mark"
      },
      {
        key: 7,
        name: "Steve"
      }
    ],
    selectedPerson: 1,
    prev: 0,
    isChanged: false
  },
  methods: {
    myEvent: function(e) {
      if (e.type == "input" || (e.type == "click" && !this.isChanged && (this.prev == this.selectedPerson || this.prev == 0))) {
        this.isChanged = true;
        this.prev = 0;
      } else if (e.type == "click" && this.isChanged) {
        console.log(e.type, this.selectedPerson);
        this.prev = this.selectedPerson;
        this.isChanged = false;
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  height: 39px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: The code works with or without `@input="myEvent($event)"`. Please confirm. Also, I am not sure how `e.which` is doing the job here. Also also, it seems that `e.which` is [non standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/which) which should be mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Yes it works without `input` event but OP had it in the question so I included it

Comment: `e.which` was the only property in `MouseEvent` I could exploit to to get the result where the click is differentiated between click on `select` and `option`, will include all you've mentioned in the answer :)

Comment: How does `e.which` do that though? I thought the number 0 meant it is a left click? How does that differentiate?

Comment: @RashadSaleh [`UIEvent.detail`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/detail) has the same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

when you change the dropdown you will get the index of people array and you can do something like this to get value

```
    myEvent: function() {
    console.log(this.people[this.selectedPerson].name);
    }
   }
```

Comment: to be fair, when I run this fiddle, I get an error when I select Carl,or gives me the wrong name entirely.

Answer (score 0):

one workaround is to set selected to a not used value when focus, then change event will fire no matter which option is selected.

```
<select 
    v-model="selectedPerson" 
    ref="s" 
    @focus="selectedPerson = 0" 
    @change="myEvent()"
>
```

see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tne1wp3q/

it's not perfect though, the change event will be fired multiple times with each click, and if no options were selected, it could left blank. Need more code to filter these behaviour.